# Ellipse and rectangle

Tags: conic-sections

An ellipse, whose equation is ${x^2\over9} + {y^2\over4} = 1$, is inscribed within a rectangle whose sides are parallel with the coordinate axes. Another ellipse is circumscribing the rectangle and passes through the point (0, 4). I am asked to find the eccentricity of the ellipse circumscribing the rectangle.

Is there any property which links the two ellipses? For example, I tried to check whether they would have the same focus, but that didn't come out to be true.

Comment: There is an infinite family of ellipses that circumscribe the rectangle. Are you asked to find the one with the smallest area? Or what?

Comment: Oops, forgot to mention that it passes through the point (0, 4)) @TonyK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you need a fifth point to determine the ellipse, the eccentricity is a degree of freedom and there is no useful relation to the inner ellipse.

Your red ellipse is
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{4^2}=1.$$
Plug the coordinates of a corner to determine $a$.

Comment: Ummm..... Lost you. What exactly is a red ellipse?

Comment: @Gummybears: sorry, I meant georg's red ellipse. The outer ellipse.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried (only graphically - program Geogebra) - I would say, the ellipsis would have the same focus.

[image: elipsis]

Truth has user TonyK - there is an infinite family of ellipses that circumscribe the rectangle.

Edit - followed by:

$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{16}=1,\quad (x=3, and \,y=2) \quad \Rightarrow a^2=12$

$\Rightarrow \frac{x^2}{12}+\frac{y^2}{16}=1$

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that it passes through the point (0,4). Also, when I found the answer using the assumption that they have the same focii, the answer came out to be incorrect.

Comment: I just realized that the point given was on the y-axis and therefore gave the value of b. Thanks anyways.